# Users registration details to appear on my profile form

Tags: codenameone

I have two forms one for register and the other for My Profile. I want when the user enters information and clicks REGISTER button then that information should go to the My Profile Form and be stored.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this but the simplest is to just store the data in a variable:

```
myButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    userName = userNameTextField.getText();
    // ....
});
```

Then get the data from these variables in the other form.